# Join string to 2d array, which already contains string or null

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I would like to create code, to join few text files (each one has different structure) into one with unifying build.

For now, I manage to open all files, split strings in rows by tabulator and save everything into one two dimensional lists.

```
Example of current data: 
809187.49   226885.80   26934
809183.14   226877.21   26937a
2   5509514.58  6558911.86  0.00    80T
3   5509515.55  6558913.48  0.00    80T
4   5509516.35  6558914.56  0.00    80T
```

Next, I am going to reprint content from a two-dimensional list into a new array (with n rows and 2 columns) and sort all data at the same time. All double type, greater then 100000.00 I want to put into the second column with ',' separator and the rest of content of each row from the list I would like to put into the first column:

```
Result:
26934   809187.49,226885.80
26937a  809183.14,226877.21
2,0.00,80T  5509514.58,6558911.86
3,0.00,80T  5509515.55,6558913.48
4,0.00,80T  5509516.35,6558914.56
```

And here is the problem. I used code like below:

```
string[,] resultArray = new string[RowNo, 2]; //Create Array 

for (int i = 0; i < resultList.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Regex.Matches(file[i], "    ").Count+1; j++)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(resultList[i][j], out n)) // record is a double type greater then n
        {
            if((Double.Parse(resultList[i][j]) % 1) > 0) // record is not a int type
            {
                if (resultArray[i, 1] != null) // if cell in array is not null
                {
                    resultArray[i, 1].Insert(resultArray[i, 1].Count(), "," + resultList[i][j].ToString()); // add content of List in to string in second column
                }
                else // if cell in array is null for now
                {
                    resultArray[i, 1].Insert(0, "," + resultList[i][j].ToString()); // put content of List in to second column
                }

            }

            if (resultArray[i, 0] != null) //if cell in array is not null
            {
                resultArray[i, 0].Insert(resultArray[i, 0].Count(), ";" + resultList[i][j].ToString());  // put content of List in to first column
            }
            else // if cell in array is null for now
            {
                resultArray[i, 0].Insert(0, "," + resultList[i][j].ToString());  // put content of List in to first column
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (resultArray[i, 0] != null) //if cell in array is not null
            {
                resultArray[i, 0].Insert(resultArray[i, 0].Count(), ";" + resultList[i][j].ToString());  // put content of List in to first column
            }
            else // if cell in array is null for now
            {
                resultArray[i, 0].Insert(0, "," + resultList[i][j].ToString());  // put content of List in to first column
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, when I run code I receive bug "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I have make some research and try something like this:

```
resultArray[i, 1] += resultArray[i, 1] + "," + res_file[i][j].ToString();
```

instead

```
resultArray[i, 1].Insert(resultArray[i, 1].Count(), "," + res_file[i][j].ToString());
```

But it wasn't work correctly. I received some results but data in record was duplicated.

I will appreciate every help.

Comment: You get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when you *compile*? Not when you run?

Comment: Sorry for mistake. Yes, you are right. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" appears when I run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with all your else conditions:

You are doing

```
if (resultArray[i, 0] != null) //if cell in array is not null
{
    resultArray[i, 0].Insert(resultArray[i, 0].Count(), ";" + resultList[i][j].ToString());  // put content of List in to first column
}
else // if cell in array is null for now
{
    resultArray[i, 0].Insert(0, "," + resultList[i][j].ToString());  // put content of List in to first column
}
```

which basically means do if block when `resultArray[i, 0] != null`, but in the else block you are trying to access the `Insert()` method of that null object. Hence the error. All of your `else` blocks are like that.

*I think* what you want to do is an assignment in your else blocks (which you seem to have figured out)... like:

```
resultArray[i, 0] += "," + resultList[i][j].ToString());
```

The problem with duplicates may have been that you are using both `+=` and the left hand side (LHS) expression in

`resultArray[i, 1] += resultArray[i, 1] + "," + res_file[i][j].ToString();`

When you do `x += 1;` it is same as `x = x + 1;`

You are doing: `x += x + 1;` which is same as `x = x + (x + 1);`

Comment: Yes, I understand what cause a problem with duplicated data, thats why I decided to leave this solution. But have you any ideas how can I solve problem with populating array containing only nulls?

Comment: Do you still get duplicates if you use resultArray[i, 0] += "," + resultList[i][j].ToString());?

Comment: No. Working fine. Thanks a lot :)